# Vertex Shader not bound when running an application in DirectX 11 in VS2012

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, directx-11, vertex-shader

For my university course I have been given a number of example base applications that show different features and things that can be achieved using DirectX 11. On the University Computers and some others these all run fine. However on my laptop, not the most powerful of machines, some applications work fine while others run but only show a blank window with just the screen background colour. Looking in the output window there are a large number of D3D11 errors stating that a vertex shader is not bound hence nothing is visible on screen.

Two of those errors that appear in the debug window (they dont appear in the error list) are:

```
D3D11 ERROR: ID3D11DeviceContext::DrawAuto: A Vertex Shader is always required when drawing, but none is currently bound. [ EXECUTION ERROR #341: DEVICE_DRAW_VERTEX_SHADER_NOT_SET]
D3D11 ERROR: ID3D11DeviceContext::DrawAuto: Rasterization Unit is enabled (PixelShader is not NULL or Depth/Stencil test is enabled and RasterizedStream is not D3D11_SO_NO_RASTERIZED_STREAM) but position is not provided by the last shader before the Rasterization Unit. [ EXECUTION ERROR #362: DEVICE_DRAW_POSITION_NOT_PRESENT]
```

These programs do however run correctly on other machines. Is there some kind of configuration that I need to do on my laptop or is it likely due to the lower technical capabilities even though some applications do work?

Comment: Have you verified that `CreateVertexShader` succeeds? My guess is that you are compiling `vs_4_0` or higher, and trying to create it on a `FEATURE_LEVEL_9_3` (or `_9_1`) device. This results in failed creation, so you end up passing NULL to `VSSetShader`. The fix is to compile the shader for the `vs_4_0_level_9_3` (or `_9_1`) target.